# Drupal 7: Using Rules to add user to OG then assign OG role

Tags: drupal-7, user-roles, organic-groups, drupal-rules

The idea is to accomplish the following when a new user is added:

- Create a new group (OG)
- Save it
- Add user to saved group (OG)
- Assign group role (OG)

I am using Rules with Organic Groups. All is fine apart from assigning the group role. I know you can add general system roles but does anyone know how to assign a group (OG) role programmaticaly so it happens automagically?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find a viable solution to this? I'm looking for one myself, and you never chose any of the ones as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following custom php action on a rule, to add user to group and assign OG role.

OG role numbers appear to be in order of OG roles, as viewed through admin/config OG entries.

```
global $user;

// Load the user we want to add to the group
$account = user_load($user->uid);    

// Add the user to the group - hard code group 18 which is my group as cant 
// get PID from Ubercart order, to pull gid from nid. User, current user, active, 
// etc., all default in 2nd array() param to og_group.
og_group(18);

// Changes the users role in the group (1 = non-member, 2 = member, 3 = administrator member, 4 = Forum Administrator)
og_role_grant(18, $account->uid, 2);
```

---

Note, OG role 4 (forum administrator) is a custom OG role I created.  Also, 'member' (2) is the default, I believe, but I put this in so I'd remember how to allocate other OG roles if I needed to in future.

I'm not a php guru unfortunately, and I still havent worked out how to pull the pid from the node of the Ubercart product ordered so I can get its gid and hence not hard code the gid of 18.

Hope the above code snipped (og_role_grant mainly) works for you as a rule action custom php code snippet (remember not to include the php tags at top and bottom as rules does this for you).

If you have any thoughts on my problem of getting the gid of the ordered ubercart product, as above, please feel free to share.  :)

Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposed Organic Group patch that add this functionality to the Organic Group Rules integration.

You can find the patch here: https://drupal.org/node/1327326

It adds Grant and Revoke role actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **og_role_grant($group_type, $gid, $uid, $rid)** to assign a role to a user into an organic group programmatically.

To use this with rules, you can define a custom action using **hook_rules_action_info()** .